# Increase or Decrease Number of Stock

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to add or minus the number of medicine stock that is being stored. Are there better ways to do better than mine.

```
 @if(count($medicines) > 0)
    @foreach($medicines as $medicine)
       @if($medicine->medicine_details==="Non-Prescribed")
          <tr>
             <th scope="row">{{$medicine->medicine_name}}</th>
             <th scope="row">{{$medicine->medicine_details}}</th>
             <td>{{$medicine->medicine_qty}}
                @include('forms.incrementMed')
             </td>
             </tbody>
       @endif
    @endforeach
 @endif
```

This is the Form that I included

```
  @if( $medicine->medicine_qty < 100)
     <input style="width: 50px;" class="box" type="number" id="qty" value="qty"> 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" name="addMed" id="addMed" >Add</button>
  @elseif( $medicine->medicine_qty >= 100)
     <input style="width: 50px;" class="box" type="number" id="qty" value="qty"> 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" name="minusMed" id="minusMed" >Minus</button>                            
  @endif
```

And how do I change the value of the stored medicine_qty to the new one that is being added or minus

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" name="{{$medicine->medicine_qty < 100? addMed :'minusMed' }}" id="{{$medicine->medicine_qty < 100? addMed :'minusMed' }}" >{{$medicine->medicine_qty < 100? 'ADD':'Minus' }}</button>
```

Comment: how to get the qty inputed so that it will be subtracted in the medicine_qty?